# how can i simulate fliping effect of image

Tags: android, user-interface, android-layout

i been creating my first application iam stuck with following problem

```
  when clicking a particular button it will display flipping of
```

current (rotate layout in the direction of the perpendicular to screen 
and about an axis parallel to to screen) ui and go to another ui that for
 setting preferences of the application how can i simulate effect of that
 flip

```
    is there any better way for doing that
```

Comment: This is a bit unclear. You may want to add more information. For example, what code do you have functioning right now? What are you trying to accomplish? In #1 you talk about buttons, but in #2 you reference images.. what exactly are you working with?

Comment: @Snailer thanks for the quick reply,Actully that are two two points where i stucked ,while developing simple Calculator application.  i updated my question hope u can understand Q better

Answer (score 1):

Here is link for animation-->

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/animation/index.html

use 3d raotation u can rotate ............